rtk query merge data, tags, mutation
i have 2 endpoints they are linked by tagTypes,
first endpoint is a get query and that evry time when i click button show more is refetching and merge current data with new data,
second endpoint is mutation that add a new user
export const usersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "userApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "url" }),
  tagTypes: ['User'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
        query: ({page}) => `users?page=${page}&count=6`,
        serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
            return endpointName
          },
        merge: (currentCache, newItems, {arg}) => {
            currentCache?.users?.push(...newItems?.users)
        },
        forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
            return currentArg !== previousArg
        },
        providesTags: ['User']
        }),
    createNewUser: builder.mutation({
      query: ({token, formData}) => ({
        url: `users`,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Token': token,
        },
        body: formData,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['User'],
    })
    }) 
})

problem is that when i add new user, first endpoint is refetching and merging current and new data, i don't need it, how i can clear current cache after evry mutation for first endpoint?

You can add an onQueryStarted handler to the createNewUser endpoint that dispatches an action to update the cache of the getUsers endpoint. This is basically the same as applying Optimistic Updates.
Basic Example:
export const usersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "userApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "url" }),
  tagTypes: ['User'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: ({ page }) => `users?page=${page}&count=6`,
      serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
        return endpointName
      },
      merge: (currentCache, newItems, { arg }) => {
        currentCache?.users?.push(...newItems?.users)
      },
      forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg
      },
      providesTags: ['User']
    }),
    createNewUser: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ token, formData }) => ({
        url: `users`,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Token': token,
        },
        body: formData,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['User'],
      onQueryStarted: async (arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
        // Dispatch API utility to update the getUsers endpoint cache
        const patchResult = dispatch(usersApi.util.updateQueryData(
          "getUsers",
          undefined,
          draft => {
            // check this access, I'm just guessing based on information
            // provided above in getUsers cache merging
            draft.users = [];
          }
        ));
    
        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
        } catch {
          // Undo if there were any mutation errors
          patchResult.undo();
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});


is working great, but now have another problem, after clear cache data in onQueryStatred i need to reset page arg from first endpoint, i tryed to createSlice for page and after dispatch(setPage(1)) in draft after clear cache data but is going two request how i can reset page arg?

@itanmare That seems like a logical approach. Do you mind asking that as a new post? You can reference your work in this post if you like. You'll get more eyes on your problem more quickly this way as well. Feel free to ping me in a comment here with a link to any new post you create and I can take a look when available.
